# Entity Framework multiple search with empty variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to search multiple and get results. I send this function `devicename` `user` `alarm`. When these variables are filled, it works. but when they are empty, it's not. I can fill only `devicename` variable. For example;

```
devicename = "test"; 
alarm=""; 
user="";
```

Sometimes I can fill `devicename` `user`, sometimes I can fill `devicename` `alarm`.. I can't get any data from my code. I need help. here is my code:

```
List<ActivityLog> list = db.ActivityLog.Where(c => c.Devices.devName.ToLower().Contains(devicename.ToLower()))
                                       .Where(c => c.Users.uName.ToLower().Contains(user.ToLower()))
                                       .Where(c => c.AlarmCodes.aName.ToLower().Contains(alarm.ToLower()))
                                       .OrderBy(c => c.dateTime).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        List<ActivityLog> list = db.ActivityLog.Where(c => devicename == "" || c.Devices.devName.ToLower().Contains(devicename.ToLower()))
                                               .Where(c => user == "" || c.Users.uName.ToLower().Contains(user.ToLower()))
                                               .Where(c => alarm == "" || c.AlarmCodes.aName.ToLower().Contains(alarm.ToLower()))
                                               .OrderBy(c => c.dateTime).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

and as Mihai suggested you can combine all where statements.

Comment: it gives error : **this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Answer (score 3):

I have done this in the past.

```
public IQueryable<ActivityLog> ApplyCriteria(Context db)
{
    var activitySet = db.ActivityLog.AsQueryable();

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceName))
        activitySet.Where(c => c.Devices.devName.ToLower().Contains(devicename.ToLower());

    //and so on and so forth
    return activitySet;
}

public Response SearchStuff(Criteria criteria)
{
    using(var db = CreateContext())
    {
        var qry = criteria.ApplyApplyCriteria(db);
        //In this instance, whatever is a list on my response object, but I believe it could be
        //anything that handles IEnumerable
        response.Whatever.AddRange(qry);
    }
}
```

And just built my query that way. Then in the caller of the criteria I can handle the Queryable however I want.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but I will elaborate a bit more on what I do when applying criteria. Let me edit my answer right quick :)

Answer (score 2):

can you put all those where in a sigle one with OR condition betwen them? Like this it acts like AND operation.

```
.ActivityLog.Where(c => c.Devices.devName.ToLower().Contains(devicename.ToLower()) ||
                       c.Users.uName.ToLower().Contains(user.ToLower()) || 
                       c.AlarmCodes.aName.ToLower().Contains(alarm.ToLower()))
             .OrderBy(c => c.dateTime).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: oh I see that when I fill 2 variable and I don't fill one variable it gives all data.